# CSS Transitions - Opacity change on div but not div content

Tags: css, html, z-index, transition

First off I want to you to know that i'm a beginner in CSS so this might be a easy/stupid question. Im trying to create a div with a picture inside it, and when it's hovered the picture changes opacity and 3 boxes with icons appear. The problem is that I get the boxes opacity changed as well since it's in the same div, but if I put it outside the div the problem is when hovering over the boxes the image loses the opacity change. How can I fix this? I've tried everything that seems logical for me but with no success. Thankful for any help!

CSS code:

```
.boxfadeout {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
display: block;
}

.boxfadeout:hover {
-webkit-opacity: 0.7 !important;
-moz-opacity: 0.7 !important;
opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

.withfadeout {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
display: block;
}

.withfadeout:hover {
-webkit-opacity: 0.6 !important;
-moz-opacity: 0.6 !important;
opacity: 0.6 !important;
}

#box {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 80px;
top: 150px;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 1;
}

#box2 {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 120px;
top: 150px;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 1;
}

#box3 {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 160px;
top: 150px;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 1;
}

.white, .white a {
color: #fff;
}

.showme { 
display: none;
}

.showhim:hover .showme {
display : block;
}
```

BODY code:

```
<div class="showhim">
<div class="withfadeout"><img src=".jpg" with="300px" height="340px">
<div class="showme">
<a href="">
<div id="box" class="boxfadeout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus white"></span></div></a>
<a href="">
<div id="box2" class="boxfadeout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart white"></span></div></a>
<a href="">
<div id="box3" class="boxfadeout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart white"> </span></div></a>`enter code here`
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the opacity on the image instead:

```
div:hover img{
    opacity: .7
}
```

although @Diodeus answer is correct, it does not take in account that you may have a background with gradients or images, and would not work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works but how do I get the transition effect "all 0.5s ease" on the image to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

Opacity affects all child elements. RGBA (alpah channel) does not. Change your transition to use RBGA.